# Linked list containig different derived class objects in c++

Tags: c++, oop

How we can create a linked list which can contain a different class of object. for example, if a person is base class and it has student and teacher as a derived class so How I can create a linked list which can contain both classes of objects like student also and teacher also.
below I wrote the source code for that but it is not working.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int classNum;

class person
{
    public:
        string name;

    public:
        person(string="");
        void show_p_name();

};

class student:public person
{
    public:
        string s_name;
        int rollnum;

    public:
        student(string="", string="", int=100);
        void show_name();

};

class worker:public person
{
    public:
        string w_name;
        int work_id;

    public:
        worker(string="", string="", int=200);
        void show_name();

};

// person
person::person(string nm)
{
    name = nm;
}

void person::show_p_name()
{
    cout << "In person class name is: " << name << endl;
}

// student inheriate person
student::student(string nm, string snm, int rolln)
        :person(nm)
{

    s_name = snm;
    rollnum = rolln;
}

void student::show_name()
{
    cout << "In student class name is: " << s_name << endl;
}

// worker inheriate person
worker::worker(string nm, string wnm, int wid)
        :person(nm)
{
    w_name = wnm;
    work_id = wid;
}

void worker::show_name()
{
    cout << "In worker class name is: " << w_name << endl;
}

// structure declaration
struct Node
{
    person *p;
    struct Node *next;
};


struct Node* createNode()
{
    struct Node *t;

    t = new struct Node;

    classNum++;

    if(t == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Memory Not Allocated\n";
        //exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        return t;
    }
}

void initLink(struct Node *n)
{
    n->next = NULL;         //Make next as NULL
}

void initNode(struct Node *temp)
{

    if((classNum % 2) == 0)
    {
        /*
        temp->p = new student;
        static_cast<student*>(temp->p)->name = "person_s_sahil";
        static_cast<student*>(temp->p)->s_name = "student_sahil";
        static_cast<student*>(temp->p)->rollnum = 100;
        temp->p = static_cast<student*>(temp->p);
        */

        temp->p = new student();
        temp->p->name = "person_s_sahil";
        temp->p->s_name = "student_sahil";
        temp->p->rollnum = 100;

    }
    else
    {
        /*
        temp->p = new worker;
        static_cast<worker*>(temp->p)->name = "person_w_sahil";
        static_cast<worker*>(temp->p)->w_name = "worker_sahil";
        static_cast<worker*>(temp->p)->work_id = 100;
        temp->p = static_cast<worker*>(temp->p);
        */

       temp->p = new worker()
       temp->p->name = "person_w_sahil";
       temp->p->w_name = "worker_sahil";
       temp->p->work_id = 100;


    }


}

void attachEnd(struct Node **hptr, struct Node *tn)
{
    struct Node *cn;
    if(*hptr == NULL)  //if list is empty
    {
        *hptr = tn;   //attach new node to head
    }
    else
    {
        cn = *hptr;    //get first node call as currunt node
        while(cn->next != NULL)  //get last node
        {
            cn = cn->next;
        }
        cn->next = tn; //attach new node to next of last node
    }


}


void traverse(struct Node *hptr)
{
    struct Node *temp;
    if(hptr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "List is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        temp = hptr;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            temp->p->show_name();
            temp = temp -> next;
        }

    }
}

main()
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    struct Node *temp;

    temp = createNode();

    initLink(temp);

    initNode(temp);

    attachEnd(&head, temp);

    traverse(head);

    // like that I want to create node and attach to linked list
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of " but it is not working" ? Please explain

Comment: It showing errors, like error: ‘class person’ has no member named ‘s_name’, same for w_name, rollnum, work_id and show_name

Comment: Use `std::list<std::unique_ptr<person>>` and make your classes polymorphic (having at least virtual destructors).

Comment: Remove the struct keyword from line "struct Node *next;" and from everywhere you are refering structure Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper approach would be to create linked list of pointers to objects of type Person.
Then you will populate it with pointers to instances of classes Student and Teacher. You have to create it dynamically (new keyword)

And now magic comes with using of keyword virtual for method declaration in Person class. Check this in google **c++ polymorphism** and **C++ virtual method**
If you latter call virtual method on pointer to Person object it will call proper method from derived class.

Do not forget to call `delete` for each element in list at the end of usage (program). And for this you have to define `virtual destructor` in Person class

In your case you should define Person class like this

```
class person
{
public:
    string name;
    virtual ~person() {};

public:
    person(string="");
    virtual void show_name();
};
```

Or another approach could be to use `dynamic_cast<>()` but for this you need to enable it in compiler. It is called RTTI (runtime type information). With dynamic cast you can safely cast from Person to Student or Teacher. If dynamic cast is not able to do cast it will return `nullptr`. So you can check this value.

Comment: How I can then access all the members of the derived class please can you explain to me in more detail

Comment: @sahilmakandar To really access derived class object you have perform dynamic_cast. But I think you don't wont to do this. Rather call virtual method from parent class. This is the point, calling virtual method ensures that proper method from child object is called.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly fixed code (for purpose of compile-ability):

```
void initNode(struct Node *temp)
{

  if ((classNum % 2) == 0)
  {
    /*
    temp->p = new student;
    static_cast<student*>(temp->p)->name = "person_s_sahil";
    static_cast<student*>(temp->p)->s_name = "student_sahil";
    static_cast<student*>(temp->p)->rollnum = 100;
    temp->p = static_cast<student*>(temp->p);
    */

    auto s = new student();
    temp->p = s;
    temp->p->name = "person_s_sahil";
    s->s_name = "student_sahil";
    s->rollnum = 100;

  }
  else
  {
    /*
    temp->p = new worker;
    static_cast<worker*>(temp->p)->name = "person_w_sahil";
    static_cast<worker*>(temp->p)->w_name = "worker_sahil";
    static_cast<worker*>(temp->p)->work_id = 100;
    temp->p = static_cast<worker*>(temp->p);
    */

    auto p = new worker();
      temp->p = p;
      temp->p->name = "person_w_sahil";
    p->w_name = "worker_sahil";
    p->work_id = 100;


  }


void traverse(struct Node *hptr)
{
  struct Node *temp;
  if (hptr == NULL)
  {
    cout << "List is empty\n";
  }
  else
  {
    temp = hptr;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
      temp->p->show_p_name();
      temp = temp->next;
    }

  }
}
```

If you fix your code, it will work (at a glance).

Comment: Can I access all members of base class and derived class by using temp->p?

Comment: temp->p is pointer of a base class. And base class doesn't know about derived class. So, you can either cast base class to derived or (its better in your case) fill derived class and, after that, set to temp->p.

Comment: Also, If you want to have different functions into derived classes, that can be available from base class - you can look at 'virtual' function.

Comment: for above code it showing error: ‘p’ does not name a type
         auto p = new student();

Comment: You can write like: ```student* s = new student();```, auto is feature of newer C++

Comment: Now it showing error only here error: ‘class person’ has no member named ‘show_name’
    temp->p->show_name(); Using base class object I am not able to access derived class member. I did same , first I fill derived class and then I set to temp->p